# Java ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency

In an application where 1 thread is responsible for updating a map continuously and the main thread periodically reads the map, is it sufficient to use a ConcurrentHashmap?  Or should I explicitly lock operations in synchronize blocks?  Any explanation would be great.

**Update**

I have a getter and a setter for the map (encapsulated in a custom type) which can be used simultaneously by both threads, is a ConcurrentHashMap still a good solution?  Or maybe I should synchronize the getter/setter (or perhaps declare the instance variable to be volatile)?  Just want to make sure that this extra detail doesn't change the solution.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you perform all operation in one method call to the concurrent hash map, you don't need to use additional locking. Unfortunately if you need to perform a number of methods atomically, you have to use locking, in which case using concurrent hash map doesn't help and you may as well use a plain HashMap.

@James' suggestion got me thinking as to whether tuning un-need concurrency makes a ConcurrentHashMap faster. It should reduce memory, but you would need to have thousands of these to make much difference. So I wrote this test and it doesn't appear obvious that you would always need to tune the concurrency level.

```
warmup: Average access time 36 ns.
warmup2: Average access time 28 ns.
1 concurrency: Average access time 25 ns.
2 concurrency: Average access time 25 ns.
4 concurrency: Average access time 25 ns.
8 concurrency: Average access time 25 ns.
16 concurrency: Average access time 24 ns.
32 concurrency: Average access time 25 ns.
64 concurrency: Average access time 26 ns.
128 concurrency: Average access time 26 ns.
256 concurrency: Average access time 26 ns.
512 concurrency: Average access time 27 ns.
1024 concurrency: Average access time 28 ns.
```

Code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("warmup", new ConcurrentHashMap());
    test("warmup2", new ConcurrentHashMap());
    for(int i=1;i<=1024;i+=i)
    test(i+" concurrency", new ConcurrentHashMap(16, 0.75f, i));
}

private static void test(String description, ConcurrentHashMap map) {
    Integer[] ints = new Integer[2000];
    for(int i=0;i<ints.length;i++)
        ints[i] = i;
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for(int i=0;i<20*1000*1000;i+=ints.length) {
        for (Integer j : ints) {
            map.put(j,1);
            map.get(j);
        }
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.println(description+": Average access time "+(time/20/1000/1000/2)+" ns.");
}
```

As @bestss points out, a larger concurrency level can be slower as it has poorer caching characteristics.

EDIT: Further to @betsss concern about whether loops get optimised if there is no method calls.  Here is three loops, all the same but iterate a different number of times. They print

```
10M: Time per loop 661 ps.
100K: Time per loop 26490 ps.
1M: Time per loop 19718 ps.
10M: Time per loop 4 ps.
100K: Time per loop 17 ps.
1M: Time per loop 0 ps.
```

.

```
{
    int loops = 10*1000 * 1000;
    long product = 1;
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for(int i=0;i< loops;i++)
        product *= i;
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.println("10M: Time per loop "+1000*time/loops+" ps.");
}
{
    int loops = 100 * 1000;
    long product = 1;
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for(int i=0;i< loops;i++)
        product *= i;
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.println("100K: Time per loop "+1000*time/loops+" ps.");
}
{
    int loops = 1000 * 1000;
    long product = 1;
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for(int i=0;i< loops;i++)
        product *= i;
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.println("1M: Time per loop "+1000*time/loops+" ps.");
}
// code for three loops repeated
```

Comment: not entirely true.  for instance, updating the map might require multiple calls which need external sync, but reading the map may still be a single method call, in which case a ConcurrentMap would still make sense (with only the update method externally synchronized).

Comment: Are you talking about needing multiple puts to be acted upon as as a single operation? In such a case, `ConcurrentHashMap` is not a valid solution, because its level of atomicity is a single `put` operation.

Comment: the test always uses the same locks. so it doesn't matter what is the "concurrency level". it will not use more than 2 locks, no matter what, it will never get a cache-miss either, during the loop either. Btw, why would you need external sync. using the ConcurrentMap, you can do retries w/ map.replace()

Comment: @bestsss, my point is that having more concurrent level than you use won't slow it down, so there is little point reducing it other than to save memory.  Repeated map.replace() assumes the object is free. If creating the object is considered expensive, replace doesn't avoid the need to create it first.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: well, having more locks to strip (concurrency level) would mean more cases of cache-misses and the test doesn't have cache-misses at all and doesn't exploit different lock strips. Certainly, the slow down won't be any noticeable with high 'concurrency-level'.  As for replace/retry: any concurrent program must expect the map can be altered at any time, so it should use only a local (at the stack) object and perform the operations with it. Well written retry loops shall not need locking. But writing big lock-free algorithms is just difficult (or very difficult).

Comment: @bestsss, I have changed the test to use 2000 keys to show the map does slow down with higher levels of concurrency.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: I'd never think you'd see the drop of performance in a microbencmark since it's always in the CPU cache. Btw, to warm up the method "test" must be called 10000 times for -server (w/ the default settings, 1000 for client), it should get even better it's optimized.

Comment: @bestsss, The count also applies to loops. ;) Its not a requirement that the whole method be called than many times.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: yes, the CHM put/get will be compiled but it will not be inlined in the code.

Comment: @bestsss, I added code to run test() 20K times and then did the same test again and I got the same results.  My understanding is that loops executed enough times are optimised.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: the counter should be per method or a lost CAS to go for the real compiler. On the other hand CHM is never used by any other code (with different keys), so it can be practically optimized for Integer. Here is a good guideline paper on microbenchmarks http://www.azulsystems.com/events/javaone_2002/microbenchmarks.pdf I can look for some more references explaining how/when hotspot decided to compile

Comment: @bestsss, Added demonstration code optimised by looping alone.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: I saw that and I do appreciate the depths you go. It's nice to see passion :). About loop optimizations, I think Hotspot does on the stack (frame) optimization on the fly, i.e. compiles the method while firstly has started in interpretation mode. Since not all the profiling info has been collected it uses the faster and not so smart compiler and doesn't perform all possible optimizations. But dead-code optimization should be simple enough. One method in real-world application can be optimized/deoptimized/optimized again. Back to CHM put/get I think even w/ full inline

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: ...there should be no difference to the code you have.

Answer (score 1):

That is sufficient, as the purpose of `ConcurrentHashMap` is to allow lockless get / put operations, but make sure you are using it with the correct concurrency level.  From the docs:

`Ideally, you should choose a value to accommodate as many threads as will ever concurrently modify the table. Using a significantly higher value than you need can waste space and time, and a significantly lower value can lead to thread contention. But overestimates and underestimates within an order of magnitude do not usually have much noticeable impact. A value of one is appropriate when it is known that only one thread will modify and all others will only read. Also, resizing this or any other kind of hash table is a relatively slow operation, so, when possible, it is a good idea to provide estimates of expected table sizes in constructors.`

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html.

EDIT:

The wrappered getter/setter make no difference so long as it is still being read/written to by multiple threads.  You *could* concurrently lock the whole map, but that defeats the purpose of using a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: +0: The default concurrency level is 16, to increase this you would need to have more than 16 cores actively using the hash map (rather than doing something else useful) e.g. say you have an application using 100 cores (not just threads) but it spends less than 10% of the time accessing the Map, you wouldn't need to tune the concurrency level. In 99.9% of applications/machines tuning this is not a problem.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, but the documentation specifically mentions lowering it from 16 can improve performance if you know how many threads will be accessing it.  See nanda's answer.

Comment: my preference would be to have a small number of ConcurrentHashMaps so I wouldn't suggest you would need to reduce their size. They are relatively expensive, but still very small individually.

Comment: On my machine a default ConcurrentHashMap uses about 2.5K which is relatively expensive but you would still need about 5000 of these to use one dollars worth of memory, in which case you don't need to be using ConcurrentHashMap as you will never have that many cores accessing them at once.

Answer (score 1):

A `ConcurrentHashMap` is a good solution for a situation involving lots of write operations and fewer read operations. The downside is that it is not guaranteed what writes a reader will see at any particular moment. So if you require the reader to see the most up-to-date version of the map, it is not a good solution.

From the [Java 6 API documentation:](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset. For aggregate operations such as putAll and clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries.

If that is not acceptable for your project, your best solution is really a fully synchronous lock. Solutions for many write operations with few read operations, as far as I know, compromise up-to-date reads in order to achieve faster, non-blocked writing. If you do go with this solution, the [`Collections.synchronizedMap(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29) method creates a fully-synchronized, single reader/writer wrapper for any map object. Easier than writing your own.

Comment: What if I have a getter and a setter for the map used simultaneously be both threads, is a ConcurrentHashMap still a good solution?

Comment: +0 it uses busy waiting rather than compromising data consistency. e.g. just like AtomicInteger does. (same author) This will notionally waste CPU, but its highly unlikely you will notice it.

Comment: The whole idea behind a `ConcurrentHashMap` is that `get` operations will never block, so it is a good solution for using `get` and `put` operations simultaneously. It simply does not guarantee what `put` operations will be seen by any particular `get` operation.

Comment: @opl, ConcurrentHashMap is not a good solution to passing tasks/data between threads. There are better solutions for that.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - It will only allow reads of fully completed write operations, so it does not compromise data consistency. But it does not promise which write operations will be read. I have added a quote from the API that makes this fact clear.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using ConcurrentHashMap, as it's implementation doesn't normally block reads. If you synchronize externally, you'll end up blocking most reads, as you don't have access to the internal knowledge of the impl. needed to not do so.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one writer it should be safe to just use ConcurrentHashMap.  If you feel the need to synchronize there are other HashMaps that do the synchronization for you and will be faster than manually writing the synchronization.

Comment: wrong... ConcurrentHashMap can also accommodate more than 1 writer

Comment: @nanda I didn't say it couldn't.  What I said was IF there is only one writer.  @opl said he only had one thread writing.

Comment: @Endophage yes but the way your sentence built suggests that it doesn't work with more than one writer

Comment: @nanda I think maybe English isn't your first language?  Taken in the context of the question it is very clear.

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap does use locking - it just improves things by only locking the relevant bucket in use (lock striping).  Even with multiple writers the chances are that there will not be contention.

Comment: @Highland Mark agreed, I was simply saying that when you have only one writer accessing your HashMap, using an unsynchronized Map, that is, ConcurrentHashMap, is safe under normal conditions.

Comment: Agree with @Highland Mark, exactly what I'm suggested

Comment: @nanda, not exactly what was said.  But worth point out that you can have up to the concurrency level number of writers at once. (16 by default)

Comment: @Highland Mark From the java api for ConcurrentHashMap: "retrieval operations do not entail locking"

Comment: @nanda I'm not debating how many writers you CAN have, I was answering the question given that we know @opl will only have ONE writer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... and to optimize it better, you should set the concurrency level to 1.

From Javadoc:

> The allowed concurrency among update operations is guided by the optional concurrencyLevel constructor argument (default 16), which is used as a hint for internal sizing. .... A value of one is appropriate when it is known that only one thread will modify and all others will only read.

Answer (score 0):

The solution works because of memory consistency effects for ConcurrentMaps: As with other concurrent collections, actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a ConcurrentMap as a key or value happen-before actions subsequent to the access or removal of that object from the ConcurrentMap in another thread.